# How can I compute numerically mixed partial derivatives of a function without SymPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, derivative

How can I calculate mixed partial derivatives a function: [image]? I understand there is a SymPy way of doing this, but I would prefer numeric computation with the standard and established numeric techniques for calculating partial derivatives of any order (Abramowitz, Stegun Ch 25). `scipy.misc.derivative` can do it for single variable but not for the mixed ones.

```
import numpy as np
def f(x, y):
    return (np.sin(x) + np.tanh(y))*x*y
```

Comment: Although what you're defining is a 'function' in Python and that's semantically correct, it's not the same as a mathematical 'function' that has a derivative. You need to represent the mathematical structure of the function for some other function to be able to operate on it to derive a derivative (for example second and third order derivatives like the ones you're after). So, you will end up using something like `sympy`, or a similar library that has a way to 'understand' the function mathematically - there's no derivatives of code.

Comment: @Grismar: But there *are* derivatives of code and automatic differentiation is the new hotness that pretty much all modern machine learning methods are based on. I do hope the OP actually means $\partial ^2 f / \partial x  \partial y$ otherwise I don't understand what mixed derivative is being referred to

Comment: Ah @talonmies, if automatic differentiation is what OP is after (my bad for misinterpreting), then `autograd` or `casadi` are probably what they should be looking into. However, that makes this question a "what is the best library for X" type question, which doesn't really belong on SO as an opinion-based question.

Comment: You can implement a function that computes the derivative of f on x for given x,y, and this is another function of x,y. Now you can compute the derivative on y. Alternatively, from the 1D formula you can establish the formula for the numerical derivative of x followed by numerical derivative on y.